# STM32MP1 read memory A7

Tags: linux, stm32

I am using **STM32MP157C-DK2** board and I want to share memory between to processor. My idea is to update variable in the **M4 core** and then read it in the **A7 core** (linux).
To do this, I create a section in **SRAM3** (both cores can access) and save the variable in it:

STM32MP157CACX_RAM.ld

```
 /* MODIFICATION STARTS HERE */
  .buffer(NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN (1);
    
    . = ABSOLUTE (0x10041000);
    *(.TxBuffer)
       
  } > SRAM3_ipc_shm
```

Main.c

```
uint8_t x[4] __attribute__ ((section(".TxBuffer"), used));
```

I have debugged and checked that the variable is saved in the section memory.

Now I am trying to read this on Linux side but I am not getting it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Telmo